# How to generate a 4096 key size token-signing certificate in ADFS

Tags: ssl-certificate, saml-2.0, adfs4.0

I am trying to test ADFS SAML2.0 with token-signing certificate of key size 4096 but whenever I generate ADFS certificate of 4096 key, it by default generates a token-signing of 2048 bits.

I am using the below command to generate ADFS self-signed cert.

`New-SelfSignedCertificateEx -Subject 'CN=adfs.saml.net' -ProviderName "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -KeyLength 4096 -FriendlyName 'ADFS2 SelfSigned' -SignatureAlgorithm sha256 -EKU "Server Authentication", "Client authentication" -KeyUsage "KeyEncipherment, DigitalSignature" -Exportable -StoreLocation "LocalMachine"`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORuQF.png)

I am able to authenticate SAML2.0 with the default token-signing cert of 2048 key size but I want to generate token-signing of 4096 key length (using ADFS only), any idea on how I can achieve the same. Thanks in advance!